# Unable to update nested array in mongodb using nodeJs, and no error throwing

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to update nested array in **mongodb using nodejs**. I have tried like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35823729/4336740) but not helped and even its not throwing error.

**My Collection is this**

```
{
    "country_details": [
    {
        "cities": [
            "Abbeville"
        ],
        "_id": "5a6ec189bb68bb09105eabe8",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "countryName": "United States"
    }
],
    "deletion_indicator": "N",
    "_id": "5a6ec189bb68bb09105eabe7",
    "date_created": "Mon Jan 29 2018 12:09:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "__v": 0
}
```

and I want to **update cities**, And I have try like one

```
let query = {_id: "5a6ec189bb68bb09105eabe7", countryCode: "US", countryName: "United States"};

countryAndCitiesModel.collection.update(
    query,
    {$push: {"country_details.$.cities": "ABC"}},

    (err, result)=> {
    if(err){
        return next(err);
    }else{
        return next(result);
    }
});
```

not getting update, but **getting result** like is

```
{
    "ok": 1,
    "nModified": 0,
    "n": 0
}
```

Please help.. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to match `countryCode` and `countryName` which are properties of nested object `country_details` and that's why your query can't match any document. To fix that you should fix paths to your fields:

```
db.collection.update(
    {_id: "5a6ec189bb68bb09105eabe7", "country_details.countryCode": "US", "country_details.countryName": "United States"},
    {$push: {"country_details.$.cities": "ABC"}})
```

Comment: Not helped, bro

Comment: again same response.

Comment: Bro, solved my issue, actually I am directly using the collection instead of whole db, my issue is i am trying like countryAndCitiesModel.collection.update, now i have replaced with countryAndCitiesModel.update,